# What does 'hard talking' mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

The following is from The Chronicles of Narnia(The Magician's Nephew)by C. S. Lewis.

> They stared very hard at one another, trying to remember. And then, at
>   exactly the same moment, she shouted out “Mr. Ketterley” and he
>   shouted out “Uncle Andrew,” and they knew who they were and began to
>   remember the whole story. After a few minutes of **hard talking** they
>   had got it straight.

I can't figure out the definition of '[hard](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hard)' here. 'Intense' or 'factual' seems close, but I am just guessing. Does '**hard talking**' have different meanings in different situations?

Comment: "hard talking" can refer to a rough manner of speaking, speech that uses more than a sprinkle of expletives. But here, as Andrew says, it means "intense" or "concentrated", analogous to "hard thinking".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for  **hard talking** with [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hard%20talking%2C%20straight%20talking&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chard%20talking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstraight%20talking%3B%2Cc0), there are few examples and most of them are not relevant: things like "I find it hard talking about this" and "They are hard-working, hard-living, and hard-talking".

Here is one of the few comparable usages:

> Throughout the **hard talking** that took place I noticed how carefully Mo Mowlam had to choose her words and yet every word was spoken from her heart. [Official Journal of the European Communities](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=kg-Y7AED_oMC&q=%22hard%20talking%22&dq=%22hard%20talking%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM0qDXoMfYAhWJLpQKHT5HDI04ChDoAQhDMAc)

When used in this way, I think it's safe to say that the expression **hard talking** is not widely enough used to have a distinct meaning. In the example that you quoted, **intense** is probably a reasonable interpretation.